# python - extract coordinates from a variable string

Tags: python

I have a latitude and longitude that come in a string like this:

```
my_string ='(31.251, -98.877)'
```

I would like to use Python to extract the coordinates from the above string.

The problem is that sometimes the string has variable length so one time it might look like this `(31.25134, -98.877)` or `(31.25134, -98.877435)`.

So if I do something like `my_string[9:15]` to extract the last number (the longitude) if the first number (the latitude) is longer I capture the  ')' too and that's not good.

Any idea how I might be able to extract those coordinates correctly from that string?
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
mystr = '(31.251, -98.877)'

lat, lng = map(float, mystr.strip('()').split(','))
```

Should work without regard to the length of the values.

Comment: +1 for showing a solution using basic building blocks(map, float, strip, split) that every Python programmer should learn. Bonus: it doesn't fail if the parentheses are missing.

Comment: @John: Python tuples only require the parens for disambiguation; they aren't required for the grammar.

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('(31.251, -98.877)')
(31.251, -98.877)
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine - I hadn't seen `ast.literal_eval` before.

Comment: +1 for taking advantage of the fact that the data is already in a format Python can parse. I imagine this will be slower than some of the other solutions, but it's hard to beat its elegance...

Answer (score 2):

```
(x, y) = (float(x) for x in my_string[1:-1].split(","))
```